# Can I prevent Object.ToString() on a type?

Tags: c#

Given a type like this:

```cs
class Supplier
{
    public Supplier(string name) => Name = name;

    public string Name { get; }
}
```

When refactoring code where object `supplier` previously was of type `string`, to code where object `supplier` is now of type `Supplier`, I will risk missing to change this type of code:

```cs
var supplier = new Supplier("Acme Inc.");
Console.WriteLine($"foo bar {supplier}");      // foo bar Supplier
Console.WriteLine($"foo bar {supplier.Name}"); // foo bar Acme Inc.
```

The problem is obviously that the first output line still compiles, but produces a non-expected string since `ToString` in `Object` returns the name of the type of the object.

**Is there anyway I can prevent the first output line to compile?**

Or is the only help I can get to override `ToString`:

```cs
public override string ToString() => Name;
```

Comment: You can override ToString, so it will throw exception. If test coverage is good enough, you will quickly find all usages

Comment: "Or is the only help I can get to override ToString to return the Name"? Isn't that exactly what you actually need?

Comment: What is the problem with the code compiling? Why do you want a compiler-error?? I think you should just fix the `ToString`-implementation for `Supplier` by something meaningful.

Comment: Preventing ToString from working undoubtedly also will give problems with the debugger which first shows the output of exactly that method

Comment: Interesting, adding `[Obsolete("Don't use", true)]` to a overriden `ToString` seems to do nothing.

Comment: @TimSchmelter @MakePeaceGreatAgain. The reason was that I thought overriding ToString would be a workaround and "hide" code that I in fact shouldn't really keep as `{supplier}`, rather than `{supplier.Name}`. Overriding ToString would just be a safety net preventing wrong string to be produced. I would rather change all occurrences of `{supplier}`. Also, the suggestion from @JL0PD is interesting, but it would require good test coverage, as mentioned yes. Preventing to compile in some way would give me a bullet proof refactoring. But I understand what you all are saying, I'll have to override.

Comment: @KristofferJälén the only more or less feasible option I see is to create a Roslyn analyzer.

Comment: ^^ I linked to the tutorial on creating one in my answer ...

Comment: You can't, for multiple reasons. Since every class inherits from System.Object by default, it makes things pretty hard. For example, you can't just remove `extends [mscorlib]System.Object` in the IL code and then recompile - then you'd get `TypeLoadException` every time the program starts, since the CLR expects all classes to inherit System.Object. Another reason is using `object` type and calling ToString() on it would be an issue, if your class would throw a compiler error when attempted to use ToString(). Throwing an exception is my recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap the solutions given in comments and adding some:

- override `ToString` with an Exception-Throwing implementation (useless for comp-time catch)
- override `ToString` to return `Name` property. Fixes the issue but also not *really* what you asked for.

Adding:

- create an [analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix) that detects usages. This might be **overkill**!
- manually search the codebase for "supplier" and fix where needed. Tedious and prone to miss occurrances.

Pick your poison ...

Answer (score 0):

Try using reflection for the  object in the first line as below

```
var supplier = new Supplier("Acme Inc.");
Console.WriteLine($"foo bar { typeof(supplier)}");      // foo bar Supplier
Console.WriteLine($"foo bar {supplier.Name}"); // // foo bar Acme Inc.
```

Comment: Why and how this helps?

Comment: This is not really solving the problem.

Comment: First it will help in giving output for  // foo bar Supplier --> so the reflection and Secondly for the ToString()-- we can go for Extension method also that will help to resolve the issue